# Compute the limit (using LDCT)

Tags: real-analysis

Could you please help me with the following? I think it is a Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem but I am not sure.

Compute the following:
For $1\leq p<\infty$ and $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R})$
$$\lim_{h\rightarrow \infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left|f(x+h)-f(x)\right|^p \, dx$$

Comment: This is essentially the same as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1018716/translation-operator-and-continuity or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157397/proof-that-translation-of-a-function-converges-to-function-in-l1 .

Comment: You shouldn't say "using LDCT" in the title unless the problem specifies you're supposed to use LDCT. In fact that doesn't help here...

Comment: @ PhoemueX, Normal Human, Davide Giraudo  I think the suggestion helps if the limit goes to 0 instead of infinity.